# How to expand some version keywords in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, logging, keyword-expansion

In CVS I could put `$LOG$` into the source file and when the file is checked in `$LOG$` will be expanded into true logs in the file.

But how to implement this in Mercurial? Of course I mean the other keyword such as the latest checkin date and time.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558531/how-good-is-my-method-of-embedding-version-numbers-into-my-application-using-merc/2558813#2558813 on a similar topic

Comment: But like Richard mentions in his answer, it should be avoided. See the debate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645424#645424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most of the problems keyword expansion solves it creates a whole heap more; isn't recommended in Mercurial [CVS/RCS-like Keyword Substitution - Why You Don't Need It](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordPlan) however it is documented how to do it with expansions if you really need to.

I'm not the only one [to advise against keyword expansion](http://wordaligned.org/articles/keyword-substitution-just-say-no), although there are times it can be useful one really needs to think hard before doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [keyword extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension).

A couple of important things:

1. **ONLY** add the specific files you need keyword expansion to the filename pattern in hgrc `[keyword]`.
2. The expansion is **LOCAL**. When your changeset is pushed to another repo, unless that repo also has the same keyword setup, keyword is NOT expanded.

I agree that it should be avoided whenever possible. When it is not possible to avoid is that you need to distribute a few selected files (for example, API headers) to other people (for example, API users), such that there's no way they can use hg to find out the version info.