# Keyword substituting with Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I would have a question on Mercurial with keyword expansion extension: is it possible to expand actual commit message with a keyword, so that it appears in sources for quick reference what's in the sources?

Edit: this seems to work:

in repo's hgrc

```
Log={desc}
```

But it doesn't stack, as it CVS counterpart allegedly does.

Use the Source, Luke:

*Expansions spanning more than one line and incremental expansions,
like CVS' $Log$, are not supported. A keyword template map "Log =
{desc}" expands to the first line of the changeset description.*

Comment: Just to point it out: the Mercurial Keyword Expansion wiki page advises against using it at all, and indeed it's not part of mercurial but an unsupported extension.  With a DVCS where the entire checkout is always at the same revision (unlike svn when you can do a partial checkout) there's no need for it and many reasons not to use it (make 'hg diff' hard/inaccurate).

Comment: @Ry4an : make your comment an answer, I will upvote it :)

Comment: Naw, "You don't really want to" isn't an answer.  It's true, but it's not what he's asking.

Comment: @Ry4an: It's wrong to say that the keyword extension is "not part of Mercurial" and that it is an "unsupported extension". It's a *standard* extension that is distributed with Mercurial. We provide support for standard extensions just as we do for the core code.

Comment: @neuro: I felt that this fair question needs a proper answer, despite it being slightly negative as Ry4an already noted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expand some version keywords in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032251/how-to-expand-some-version-keywords-in-mercurial)

Comment: @Ry4an: You're right, not really an answer.

Comment: @Martin: +1 for the proper answer ^^

Answer (score 6):

Keywords can only expand on a single line, so you cannot get CVS-like behavior where the [log messages keep accumulating](http://badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html). This is documented in `hg help keyword` after enabling the extension.

The commit messages are accessible with the [`{desc}` template keyword](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#templates) in Mercurial, so you can add

```
[keywordmaps]
Log = {desc}

[keyword]
**.c =
```

to have `$Log$` expanded line this in all `.c` files.

Note that the keyword extension gives a CVS-like view of the world in the way it operates on a per-file basis. Mercurial normally works on a repository-wide basis. If you do

```
$ hg commit -m "Fixed bug 123" foo.c    # create changeset 10:84e0d0dc9ce5
$ hg commit -m "Fixed bug 234" bar.c    # create changeset 11:2e85d7f2f93e
```

then it's correct that `foo.c` was last changed in revision 10, but it's wrong to say that revision 11 only contain `bar.c`. The `foo.c` file is also part of revision 11 — it is entirely plausible that the change to `bar.c` depends on the previous change to `foo.c` and so the *snapshot* in revision 11 captures the state of both `foo.c` and `bar.c`.

The [keyword extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) works on a per-file basis when it expands keywords: it will write `$Log: Fixed bug 123 $` into `foo.c` and `$Log: Fixed bug 234 $` into `bar.c` whenever you update to changeset 2e85d7f2f93e.

If you want to see why and when each file was last touched, then this will do what you want. If you want to know the global state of your repository — for example to use it as a version string! — then this is wrong. The problem is that your `version.h` file will be unchanged for long periods when you develop, and so the keywords in that file will remain unchanged too.

In that case you should really just run `hg id` as part of your `Makefile`. You can make it more fancy with something like:

```
$ hg parents --template '{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}\n'
```

which will output a string like `2.1+117-eed1e5bba9a8`. This means that your current version (eed1e5bba9a8), is 117 commits after the last tag (2.1). That makes it easy for users to compare builds made from the same central repository and you can still uniquely reproduce a build if you need to.