# Write commit history into files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, logging, cvs

In CVS you can add a `$Log$` in a file that you commit and it will save CVS commit comments into the file upon each commit. Is there anything similar for Mercurial?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyword substituting with Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752621/keyword-substituting-with-mercurial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [keyword extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) let's you do some of this. However, it doesn't support multi-line keywords like `$Log$`. It's also [not very recommended](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordPlan) to include the history like that. Running `hg log` is considered much better.