# How can I commit a file before the tag is committed?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I want to automatically bump the version of my project when I use `hg tag XXX`.

I have set up a pretag hook in my hgrc (note: I have removed the stuff that ensures it is outputting to VERSION in hg root, for clarity):

```
[hooks]
pretag.bump_version = (echo "$HG_TAG" > VERSION; hg commit -m "Updated VERSION to $HG_TAG" VERSION)
```

When I create a new tag:

```
$ hg tag 1.1
```

I get the error:

```
warning: ignoring unknown working parent <revision_id>!
```

I can use a tag hook instead, which succeeds, but then the VERSION number is exactly one revision later than the tag: which means that updating to the tagged revision, and then building will result in the product's version number (which depends upon the VERSION file) will be incorrect.

Is there a better way to handle this? I've looked at [SO question #2558531](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558531/how-good-is-my-method-of-embedding-version-numbers-into-my-application-using-mer), but that deals with updating the version number each time: I just want to update the version number *before* I tag the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to a `pre-tag` instead of a `pretag` hook.  The hook `pretag` is a special hook which is aware that you're tagging.  By contrast the `pre-tag` hook is a generic `pre-*` hook which is run before the tag command launches at all and is completely unaware that it's tagging -- which means it runs earlier too.  (There are pre-* hooks for everything even, say, `pre-log`).

I got your example to work like this:

```
[hooks]
pre-tag.bump_version = echo $HG_ARGS > VERSION; hg commit -m "updated version to $HG_ARGS" VERSION
```

Using the command line only that looked like:

```
ry4an@ry4an:~$ hg init tagtest
ry4an@ry4an:~$ cd tagtest
ry4an@ry4an:~/tagtest$ echo text > VERSION
ry4an@ry4an:~/tagtest$ hg commit -A -m initial
adding file
ry4an@ry4an:~/tagtest$ hg tag --config hooks.pre-tag='echo $HG_ARGS > VERSION; hg commit -m "updated version to $HG_ARGS" VERSION' 1.1
```

Notice I had to switch the argument to `$HG_ARGS` since it's a `pre-*` command that doesn't know we're tagging.  The details are in the `hgrc` manpage.

Also note I'm committing only the `VERSION` file when I commit in the hook by naming it explicitly.  You don't want to accidentally commit a bunch of debugging stuff you'd excluded from a previous commit just because you tagged.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yeah, I was only committing the VERSION file, but it was simplified when I typed it in here.

Comment: Cool.  You may notice that the `tag` command ends up in the `$HG_ARGS` variable too.  If that's a problem you can use `${HG_ARGS#tag }` instead, which removes it.  That's deep bash-only magic.

Comment: Super. I had just come up with `set -- junk $HG_ARGS`, and then was using `$3` as the tag. Yours looks nicer, but leaves a space before the tag value.

Comment: I don't think it leaves a space if you put one before the wavy bracket like I did.  At least it didn't in my test.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I thought I had tried that: maybe I didn't.